# NOPASSWD for single python script

Tags: sudo

To run a single script I made:
`/etc/sudoers.d/edison-user` contain `edison ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL` and it works fine.
But when I change it to `edison ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/home/edison/script.py` it does not.
WHY?
I need YOU to help me

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Does your visudo complain about the syntax or does the sudo complain when you try to run your script?

Comment: And, btw, this configuration is a security hole. Apparently, you're trying to allow edison user to run a script /home/edison/script.py as root. This edison user probably can put whatever he wants in that script.py and do anything. Basically, you're giving him full root rights and not just the ability to run a single script.

Comment: Visudo is all right. edison is me. I am giving permission for myself. I want to avoid typing my password only to run script.py.

Comment: then it looks fine to me. What do you get if you try to run the script with sudo ?

Comment: Sometimes I use to try new things and go deeper in my knowledge of Linux. edison ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/home/edison/script.py used to work on Ubuntu 21.04, but it gave me some problems and I moved, back, to 20.04 LTS. Config NOPASSWD for a single python script is not working anymore. I thought someone could have the answer.

Comment: I'd like to help, but I don't see your issue. What happens when you run:

    sudo /home/edison/script.py ?

Comment: Also, I would recommend to check that a line "@includedir /etc/sudoers.d" is present in /etc/sudoers. If it isn't, it means your /etc/sudoers.d/edison-user is not included in the main config and so has no effect.

Comment: bottom line, I want just a certain script to run without entering the password. The other programs should continue to demand to type the password as once happened.

Comment: #includedir /etc/sudoers.d is present. as far as I understood the # is not a comment. it is a directive.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow python to run it, so it would be something like:

edison ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/python /home/edison/script.py